# Extract Start and End Coordinates according to a defined length of not fixed interval

Tags: shell, text-processing, awk, bioinformatics

I have a file with intervals starting in the "start" column and ending in the "end" column. I have to extract the start and the end of these intervals according to a defined length that is in written in the 4th column. Also I have to print the information present in the column "score". The file look like this:

```
Input:  
chr     start   end     score  length  
chr1    237592  237601  176    320
chr1    237601  237912  176    320
chr1    521409  521601  150    320  
chr1    521601  521729  150    320
chr1    714026  714346  83     320 
chr1    805100  805201  323    340
chr1    805201  805440  323    340


Output:
chr     start   end     score  length  
chr1    237592  237912  176    320
chr1    521409  521729  150    320 
chr1    714026  714346  83     320
chr1    805100  805440  323    340
```

As you notice the length of the interval to extract is in the 5th column. Like for example the length of the interval in the output:

```
chr1    237592  237912
```

has been obtained by subtracting 237912 (in the second row of the "end" column) to 237592 (in the first row of "start" column) that is 320 (as defined in the 5th column).

Any idea is very appreciated.

Comment: You really need to explain what you are talking about.  People are not telepathic, and cannot read your mind to know what the columns in the table are, or by what algorithm you intend input to be transformed to output.  You've provided two sets of numbers, not explained what they represent or what transformation you want to apply, and then asked the world how to perform the transformation.

Comment: thanks i have edited so that the problem is understandable.

Comment: Um. "_the length of the interval to extract is in the 5th column_". What do you mean by this? The fifth column contains the number 320. Does this mean you want 320 rows? Please explain (in your question) what you mean by the phrase.

Comment: Not 320 rows just one row that come subtracting the i element in the second row of the "end" column to the j element in the first row of the "start" column. If you subtract i-j you have the length in the 5th column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is about merging lines, loosely speaking.  A line may be "merged" with the preceding line if its start coordinate is the same as the end coordinate of the line above.

The lines probably corresponds to genomic features. And the aim is to merge the features that are adjacent in the genomic sequence.

This is an `awk` script that does that:

```
$2 == end {
    # This line merges with the previous line.
    # Update end and continue with next line.

    end = $3;
    next;
}

{
    # This is an unmergeable line (start doesn't correspond to end on
    # previous line).

    # If we've processed at least the header line, print the data collected.
    # The if statement avoids printing an empty output line at the 
    # start of the output.

    if (NR > 1) {
        print chr, start, end, score, len;
    }

    # Get data from this line.

    chr = $1;
    start = $2;
    end = $3;
    score = $4;
    len = $5;
}

END {
    # At the end of input, print the data as above to output last line.
    print chr, start, end, score, len;
}
```

The script assumes sorted input and that all start coordinates are strictly less than the end coordinates (i.e. that all features lie on the positive strand).

Testing it:

```
$ awk -f script.awk data
chr start end score length
chr1 237592 237912 176 320
chr1 521409 521729 150 320
chr1 714026 714346 83 320
chr1 805100 805440 323 340
```

Answer (score 0):

To me this looks like a text file where columns are delimited by whitespace. It could be elegantly processed with `R` but shell script could do it too. What you need is to read file line by line using `for` loop. Within the loop a simple way would be to assign each column value (you could use `cut` for that) to a variable and then print variables out in order you desire. 2nd and 5th column variables added together produce the 3rd column for your output. You could print on screen each of your output lines with `echo` from the for loop. When you see the lines printing on screen to your liking, you simply redirect output of your script to a file like that `your_script.sh > your new output.txt`

Comment: The problem is that the file is huge and it is not possible to handle with R in my machine. Shell/Unix is much much faster, also consider that i have to run this script/set of commands in 75 files... Thanks for the suggestions anyway.

Comment: I see, how big are the files? You may be right I also did shell processing instead of R for the same reason.

Comment: Each file has 7.500.000 rows and these 5 columns i do not remember the amount of memory but even if i can easily import one file in R, then a list of 75 files through which run a loop for these commands is too much.. Tomorrow when am at work i will write also the size of each file. Thanks

Comment: each file is 3 Mb but as they are 75 it turns out that the last file is almost 1.5 Gb. Thanks.

Comment: I am interesting this problem how could i answer?

Comment: well just try to write a solution even if @Kusalananda explanation and solution are already perfect

Comment: how much faster awk version compared to R ?